# Does $f(x+yi):= \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ have a continuous function in 0?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, continuity

Does $f(x+yi):= \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ have a continuous function in 0 ?

I would start by changing it to $f(z) = \frac{xy}{|z|^2}$ but i cant find anything for xy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What is the limit as $x \to 0$ along the line $y=0$? What about the line $y=x$?

Comment: just a small typo, it should be along the line $y=0$

Comment: @alphaomega thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Thanks ! so for the case that x=y i got 1/2, but could you elaborate a bit more for the case if x=/=y?

Comment: @Payvand what's the answer to my first question?

Comment: could it be also 0?

Comment: @Payvand yes. So, you have two different paths ($y=0$ and $y=x$) along which you get different limits as $x\to 0$. What can you conclude?

Comment: ah so it isn't continues